# SPSS Insert Value from Dataset into SQL Query

Tags: sql, syntax, spss

I have an SQL query written into a `GET DATA` command.  It works perfectly as it is, but now I would like to modify it to take in a string value from my current dataset.

Sample query -

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD')
```

I would like the bracketed list to be a string value that already exists in my dataset (ref - [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054623/spss-syntax-concatenate-case-values-from-single-column))

I have tried several things to date including using a concatenated string in the `/SQL` portion of the `GET DATA` command.  For the concatenation I tried referencing the field itself and a scratch variable.

I've also attempted to call the command via a macro using the variable as an input.  Unfortunately, the SQL string only goes through with the variable name rather than its contents.

I've seen a few posts that recommend using the `WRITE OUT` command for similar use cases but haven't found anything regarding concatenating into an SQL query.  Would this be the only option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like `write out` is a good option for you.
Assuming you have one row of data in which `myconcat` has the value "`'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'`" (if you have more then one row in the data, first select only the one):

```
select if (the row with the full concatenated list) .
string cmd (a2000).
compute cmd=concat("define !mysqlcommand() 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field IN (", rtrim(myconcat), ")' !enddefine.").
write out = "path\create val list macro.sps" /cmd.
execute.
insert file = "path\create val list macro.sps".
```

The code writes a new syntax file where it creates a macro call. After the `insert` command runs this, you theoretically have a macro defined so when you use the macro call `!mysqlcommand` in syntax it will automatically write in the full SQL command you've created, so:

```
.
.
/sql = !mysqlcommand
.
.
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you once again Eli, that works perfectly.  Would you recommend erasing the temporary file from the code once it is no longer required?

Comment: ?? not sure what you mean - which file is temporary, and how do you mean to erase it from the code? I assume you're not talking about the file where you created the factors list, as all the idea is to automate and so enable reproducing the process of creating and using that list in the future - with new data?

Comment: Apologies, from reading other similar answers I noticed that a lot of people store the written out file in the Temp folder.  Which makes sense to me.  As soon as my syntax performs the SQL query the file is no longer required, but I guess it'll just be overwritten when it runs next anyway.

Comment: Right, on the other hand you might want to write it to your work folder (where it will be overwritten every run) for debugging purposes - can be helpful if you write out more complex macros. If you need you can add `title !mysqlcommand .` to your syntax to see the actual command written by the macro in the output window.

Comment: Good advice.  I've only recently started working with SPSS in my org so still learning the ins and outs of how the working environment is set up.  I'll bear your comment in mind as I integrate my code into the existing workflows and see what makes the most sense.  Again, thank you so much